# VBA browse excel files through userfrom and execute Vlookup

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup, userform

I am trying to create user form (like on picture) from where I would choose 2 excel files and execute Vlookup. I

[image]

I try this code but it does not execute Vlookup.

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

```
Option Explicit

Dim FileToOpen1 As Variant
Dim FileToOpen2 As Variant
Dim wb1 As Workbook
Dim wb2 As Workbook
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim rng2 As Range
Dim cl As Range


Private Sub BrowseButton1_Click()

FileToOpen1 = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Browse for your file", FileFilter:="Excel Files(*.xls*),*xls*")

If FileToOpen1 <> False Then
    
   TextBox1 = FileToOpen1

End If

End Sub

Private Sub BrowseButton2_Click()


FileToOpen2 = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Browse foy your file", FileFilter:="Excel Files(*.xls*),*xls*")

If FileToOpen2 <> False Then

    TextBox2 = FileToOpen2
 
End If

End Sub

Private Sub OK_Click()

If FileToOpen1 <> False Then
    
     Set wb1 = Application.Workbooks.Open(FileToOpen1)
     
End If

If FileToOpen2 <> False Then
    Set wb2 = Application.Workbooks.Open(FileToOpen2)  
End If

On Error Resume Next

rng1 = wb1.Sheets(1).Range("B3:B8")
Price_row = wb1.Sheets(1).Range("C3").row
Price_clm = wb1.Sheets(1).Range("C3").column

rng2 = wb2.Sheets(1).Range("A3:C8")

For Each cl In rng1
    wb1.Sheets(1).Cells(Price_row, Price_clm) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLOOKUP(cl, rng2, 2, False)
    Price_row = Price_row + 1
Next cl

End Sub
```

Comment: Remove “ On Error Resume Next” and see what line is throwing what error. For starter, you have to “set” all ranges (e.g.: set rng1 = wb1.Sheets(1).Range("B3:B8"))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing two variable definitions:

```
Dim Price_row As Long
Dim Price_clm As Long
```

And variables for range need to be assigned with `Set`

This: `Set rng2 = wb2.Sheets(1).Range("A3:C8")` instead of this `rng2 = wb2.Sheets(1).Range("A3:C8")`

Now, vlookup function in vba will throw an error when it doesnt find a value.
A workaround for this will be something like this.

```
Private Sub OK_Click()

    If FileToOpen1 <> False Then
         Set wb1 = Application.Workbooks.Open(FileToOpen1)
    End If
    
    If FileToOpen2 <> False Then
        Set wb2 = Application.Workbooks.Open(FileToOpen2)
    End If
    
    Set rng1 = wb1.Sheets(1).Range("B3:B8")
    Price_row = wb1.Sheets(1).Range("C3").Row
    Price_clm = wb1.Sheets(1).Range("C3").Column
    
    Set rng2 = wb2.Sheets(1).Range("A3:C8")
    
    For Each cl In rng1
        On Error Resume Next
        vlResult = "" 'Reset variable
        vlResult = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(cl, rng2, 2, False) 'Performs vlookup
        If Not vlResult = "" Then
            wb1.Sheets(1).Cells(Price_row, Price_clm).Value = vlResult
        Else
            wb1.Sheets(1).Cells(Price_row, Price_clm).Value = "N/A"
        End If
        
        Price_row = Price_row + 1
    Next cl

End Sub
```

*Dont forget to add the variable too.

```
Dim vlResult As String
```